# Block a URL at browser level

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, website, blocking

Does anyone have a solution (that doesn't involve editing the hosts file) to block a particular URL from FireFox?

Basic back story is that I'm trying to discipline myself. I'm spending FAR too much time over at [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com) that I want to genuinely block the site from my work PC so that every time I find myself flicking to it during work time I can't see it, but I'd like to be able to disable it during my lunch break. (So I only spend 40 minutes a day there, rather than 4 hours).

That said I don't want to block it at the router, nor for anyone else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I would do it is to install [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) (if you don't already have it)

Then you could write your own script (right click the icon, add new user script). When it asks you where to apply it to, enter "`http://*superuser.com/*`"

The script contains:

```
window.location.href = "about:blank";
```

During your lunch-break you simply de-activate that script from greasemonkey

Comment: Greasemonkey... I haven't seen this one before. I'll take a look.

Comment: Well, I got it working, but I've no idea what it wants by "namespace" so I entered junk, and it seems to work ;)

Comment: how would you do so for Google Chrome?

Comment: @think123 Greasemonkey equivalent for Google Chrome is Tampermonkey :)

Answer (score 3):

2 firefox extensions - leechblock and blocksite

Answer (score 2):

Use [AdBlock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865) to block URLs from the browser

Answer (score 1):

Block it using Parental Controls! :)!

Comment: He said at browser level, not system level.

Answer (score 0):

Use [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm) browser extension for rich domain blocking level capabilities.