# How to block a specific URL without blocking the entire domain

Tags: blocking, subdomain

Various questions have come close to this but involve using a browser extension or proxy server or only block the domain and are not questions or answers about leaving a domain unblocked while only blocking access to a specific page on that domain.

For example:
[Block a URL at browser level](https://superuser.com/questions/33208/block-a-url-at-browser-level)
[Block specific URL on web browsers](https://superuser.com/questions/393967/block-specific-url-on-web-browsers)
[How to block subreddits with BIND9?](https://superuser.com/questions/433684/how-to-block-subreddits-with-bind9)

But I'm not asking how to:
1) use a proxy (because I use opendns already),
2) use a browser extension (because I need it to work on all browsers),
3) block a whole domain,

But I must only block access to only a specific page on a domain such as `www.example.com/page`. and can not use proxies or extensions because I need a solution for a whole business network. This is not just my home computer I'm talking about here.

Unlike some of the questions linked above, I need to specifically block only certain pages on a webpage, and I don't want to block the entire domain or use a browser extension.

Comment: [The second question you linked to](http://superuser.com/q/393967/108226) looks like a duplicate to me - it too is asking for ways to block arbitrary URLs, not just entire domains or subdomains. Note also that subreddits are not subdomains, so the title of your question is a bit self-contradicting.

Comment: `reddit.com/r/NSFW` is not called a "subdomain", by the way. It's a page under the `reddit.com` domain. (`something.reddit.com` is a subdomain)

Comment: Just a note that you would probably also want to block the same under `https://pay.reddit.com`. And the mirrors (`msworddit.com`, `msoutlookit.com`, `coderedd.net`, etc.) And there's a whole lot of NSFW subreddits. And ... ... ... Let me simplify, effectively blocking selective subreddits is pretty much a lost cause.

Comment: @Indrek, yes I very much debated whether to drop this question here or in server fault... but I chose to start here. As my question is more about public servers than the private home, you may have a point. And I think that is the big difference between my question and the other questions I have reviewed.

Comment: @Bob , as for all those nsfw subreddits, opendns already takes care of those. In fact, the only way I can see reddit as it is , is by putting it on the opendns safe list.

Comment: @Moses, the reason this is not a duplicate is as I've stated above. aceinthehole is OK with using proxies or browser extensions for his home setup while I need a solution that can protect a business network and can not use proxies or browser extensions.

Answer (score 4):

Make all computers use a HTTP proxy, preferably in "transparent proxy" mode so that it wouldn't be as easy to disable. Squid or Privoxy might work, and there are specialized proxies for filtering content.

That said, good luck with filtering *all* NSFW subreddits out there.

Comment: And that's not counting the numerous mirrors.

Comment: I have heard something about this "privoxy" before but ... this suggestion is kind of like telling a kid with a fried motherboard to bust out a soldering iron. Yes with enough hours of research , a soldering iron and the right parts could be called an answer but how specifically to fix the problem is  not answered. A tool is not an answer. The privoxy manual is long and terminology is complicated and it can do WAY more than I am asking. Any How-Tos?

Comment: @Bob, mirrors are already taken care of with opendns

Comment: @JoshuaRobison I believe this answer is the most appropriate to what you're asking. There is no technology available that will filter specific pages without blocking the entire domain without using a browser extension, other than a proxy. This answer gives you the names of a few relevant products; if that's not enough information for you to go off of, you may want to consider hiring an outside consultant to set up your filtering software for you.

Comment: so far in my research I have to say you are right @nhinkle and privoxy seems to be my best bet. I have got it setup and working but I can not figure out how to add something to it to block. If I want to keep apple.com but block apple.com/itunes/*